# Add legend for every point on ggmap instead of a group variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggmap

I've got the following data frame:

```
df1 <- structure(list(City = c("Ahmadnagar", "Ahmedabad", "Akola", "Amaravati", 
"Aurangabad", "Belgaum", "Bellary", "Bengaluru", "Bhavnagar", 
"Bhiwandi", "Bhuj", "Bhusaval", "Bidar", "Bijapur", "Chanda", 
"Chikka Mandya", "Chirala", "Davangere", "Ghandinagar", "Gulbarga", 
"Guntur", "Hindupur", "Hospet", "Hubli", "Kagaznagar", "Kakinada", 
"Kalyan", "Khanapur", "Kolar", "Kolhapur", "Kurnool", "Latur", 
"Machilipatnam", "Malegaon Camp", "Mangalore", "Mumbai", "Mysore", 
"Nanded", "Nandyal", "Nasik", "Navsari", "Nellore", "Ongole", 
"Parbhani", "Porbandar", "Proddatur", "Pune", "Raichur", "Rajahmundry", 
"Rajkot", "Sangli", "Shimoga", "Surat", "Tirupati", "Vadodara", 
"Vishakhapatnam", "Vizianagaram"), State = c("Maharashtra", "Gujarat", 
"Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", 
"Karnataka", "Gujarat", "Maharashtra", "Gujarat", "Maharashtra", 
"Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Karnataka", "Gujarat", "Karnataka", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", "Maharashtra", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Maharashtra", "Andhra Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", 
"Maharashtra", "Karnataka", "Maharashtra", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Maharashtra", "Gujarat", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Maharashtra", "Gujarat", "Andhra Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", 
"Andhra Pradesh", "Gujarat", "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", "Gujarat", 
"Andhra Pradesh", "Gujarat", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh"
), Lat = c(19.094571, 23.025793, 20.709569, 20.933272, 19.880943, 
15.862643, 15.142049, 12.977063, 21.774455, 19.300229, 23.253972, 
21.043649, 17.913309, 16.827715, 19.950758, 12.545602, 15.823849, 
14.469237, 23.216667, 17.335827, 16.299737, 13.828065, 15.269537, 
15.349955, 19.331589, 16.960361, 19.243703, 21.273716, 13.137679, 
16.695633, 15.828865, 18.399487, 16.187466, 20.569974, 12.865371, 
18.987807, 12.292664, 19.160227, 15.477994, 19.999963, 20.85, 
14.449918, 15.503565, 19.268553, 21.641346, 14.7502, 18.513271, 
16.205459, 17.005171, 22.291606, 16.856777, 13.932424, 21.195944, 
13.635505, 22.299405, 17.704052, 18.11329), Long = c(74.738432, 
72.587265, 76.998103, 77.75152, 75.346739, 74.508534, 76.92398, 
77.587106, 72.152496, 73.058813, 69.669281, 75.785058, 77.530105, 
75.718988, 79.295229, 76.895078, 80.352187, 75.92375, 72.683333, 
76.83757, 80.457293, 77.491425, 76.387103, 75.138619, 79.466051, 
82.238086, 73.135537, 76.117376, 78.129989, 74.231669, 78.036021, 
76.584252, 81.13888, 74.515415, 74.842432, 72.836447, 76.638543, 
77.314971, 78.483605, 73.776887, 72.916667, 79.986967, 80.044541, 
76.770807, 69.600868, 78.548129, 73.849852, 77.35567, 81.777839, 
70.793217, 74.569196, 75.572555, 72.830232, 79.419888, 73.208119, 
83.297663, 83.397743)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -57L), groups = structure(list(
    State = c("Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
    "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
    "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
    "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh", 
    "Gujarat", "Gujarat", "Gujarat", "Gujarat", "Gujarat", "Gujarat", 
    "Gujarat", "Gujarat", "Gujarat", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", 
    "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", 
    "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", 
    "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Karnataka", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", 
    "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", 
    "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", 
    "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", 
    "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra", "Maharashtra"
    ), City = c("Chirala", "Guntur", "Hindupur", "Kagaznagar", 
    "Kakinada", "Kurnool", "Machilipatnam", "Nandyal", "Nellore", 
    "Ongole", "Proddatur", "Rajahmundry", "Tirupati", "Vishakhapatnam", 
    "Vizianagaram", "Ahmedabad", "Bhavnagar", "Bhuj", "Ghandinagar", 
    "Navsari", "Porbandar", "Rajkot", "Surat", "Vadodara", "Belgaum", 
    "Bellary", "Bengaluru", "Bidar", "Bijapur", "Chikka Mandya", 
    "Davangere", "Gulbarga", "Hospet", "Hubli", "Kolar", "Mangalore", 
    "Mysore", "Raichur", "Shimoga", "Ahmadnagar", "Akola", "Amaravati", 
    "Aurangabad", "Bhiwandi", "Bhusaval", "Chanda", "Kalyan", 
    "Khanapur", "Kolhapur", "Latur", "Malegaon Camp", "Mumbai", 
    "Nanded", "Nasik", "Parbhani", "Pune", "Sangli"), .rows = structure(list(
        17L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 31L, 33L, 39L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 
        49L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 2L, 9L, 11L, 19L, 41L, 45L, 50L, 
        53L, 55L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 
        29L, 35L, 37L, 48L, 52L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 
        27L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 44L, 47L, 51L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -57L), .drop = TRUE))
```

From which I'm generating a plot like this:
[image]

Here's the code I've used:

```
india_centroid <- c(68.18625, 6, 97.41529, 37)  
req_zoom <- calc_zoom(Long, Lat, data = df1)
map_type = get_map(location = india_centroid, zoom = req_zoom, maptype = "roadmap")
p <- ggmap(map_type, extent = "panel", legend = "bottomright", size = c(500, 600))
p + geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat, color = State), data = df1) +
  ggtitle("Cities in India")
```

So, as you can see the points are color based on the `State` column. And legend shows the names of the states they belong to. But, I need the legend to show the name of every `City` instead of the state while the colors are the same as per state.

I know that doesn't make sense because the colors will be repeated for the cities in the same state. But I need to know if it is possible. And if possible, how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a named vector of colors which assigns to each `City` the `State` color. Doing so you could map `City` on the color aes and set the colors according to the color vector via `scale_color_manual`:

```
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)

# State colors
col_state <- data.frame(
  State = sort(unique(df1$State)),
  color = scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(df1$State)))
)
# City colors
col_city <- df1 %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(City, State) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  left_join(col_state) %>% 
  select(-State) %>% 
  tibble::deframe()

india_centroid <- c(68.18625, 6, 97.41529, 37)  
req_zoom <- calc_zoom(Long, Lat, data = df1)
map_type = get_map(location = india_centroid, zoom = req_zoom, maptype = "roadmap")
p <- ggmap(map_type, extent = "panel", legend = "bottomright", size = c(500, 600))
p + geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat, color = City), data = df1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col_city) +
  ggtitle("Cities in India")
```

[image]

**EDIT** To order the legend by State you have to set the breaks accordingly. To this I would suggest to rearrange you dataset by State and make use of `forcats::fct_inorder` to convert your City column to a factor. Afterwards you could set the `breaks` of the color scale according to the `levels` of the `City` factor:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  arrange(State, City) %>% 
  mutate(City = forcats::fct_inorder(City))

p + geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat, color = City), data = df1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col_city, breaks = levels(df1$City)) +
  ggtitle("Cities in India")
```

[image]

Comment: Can I group the legend based on colors as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just made an edit to show you one approach to group the legend by State.

Comment: I tried with it and got an error with `fct_inorder`. The error says: `! 'idx' must contain one integer for each level of 'f'`

Comment: Hm. Googling for the error message I found this GH issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/issues/262. Following the workaround proposed there you could try `fct_inorder(fct_drop(City))`.

Comment: I came across that. Tried it and it didn't work